# postman body get the last 3 characters on the username

Tags: postman, substring, postman-pre-request-script

```
{
    "data": {
        "username": "tell1535",
        "password": "{{encryptedPassword}}",
        "type": "session"
    }
}
```

this is the body of my postman request
is there a way to use the value of `username` in pre request tab and set a value like

`pm.environment.set("number", usernamelast4digits)`

Update:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is overview

How to use Postman's global variable for `username` and `number`
by `JSON.parse(pm.request.body.toString())`

By JavaScript commands (slice) in `Pre-request Script` tab from input body.

[image]

Demo by Flask and Postman
To save as server.py

It has one `post API`.

The `post API` forward from the input POST body to the output body.

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import jwt

app = Flask(__name__)
    
@app.route("/sessions", methods=["POST"])
def post_test():
    content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    if (content_type == 'application/json'):
        json = request.get_json()
        encoded_jwt = jwt.encode({'username': json['data']['username']}, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
        newJson = {
            'data' : {
                'type': 'session',
                'token': encoded_jwt
            }
        }
        return jsonify(newJson), 201
    else:
        return 'Content-Type not supported!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

##### Install Dependency

```
pip install flask
pip install pyjwt
```

##### Run server

```
python server.py
```

[image]

Example
POST call

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/sessions
```

Input Body

```
{
    "data": {
        "username": "tell1535",
        "password": "{{encryptedPassword}}",
        "type": "session"
    }
}
```

Pre-request Script

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.toString());
console.log(jsonData);
pm.globals.set("username", jsonData.data.username);
pm.globals.set("number", jsonData.data.username.slice(-4));
console.log(pm.globals.get("username"));
console.log(pm.globals.get("number"));
```

Output Body

```
{
    "data": {
        "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InRlbGwxNTM1In0.V8tbNNjiEtv3MBYmwX82W-t0y0bnfLER48a9pQiK8m0",
        "type": "session"
    }
}
```

Send POST API

[image]

After send POST API
`encryptedPassword` need to assign by manually.

`username` and `number` will assign.

[image]

And debug the variable log from Postman console.

[image]

##### Conclusion

API's output will create token by Flask JWT logic.
The number variable picked up from input body by last 4 digit of `username`.

Comment: do i need to set the username like the on in image? i tried but i am getting undefined

Comment: the demo declare variable in environment variable, see upper image(last screen image) from my answer.

Comment: one question the value is from the environment variable not from `"username": "tell1535",` from the body ? is there a way to get the value from the body not from the environment?

Comment: @guradio, I revised my answer the `username` data comes from another API call. let me know if you figure out.

Comment: if I understand this correctly you get the number from the `response/Output Body` because you can change the response on my current problem I cant change the response all I can use is the data from `Input Body` is this possible to get that data ?

Comment: Usually GET API use a query parameter instead of an input body. I changed API1 with get API.
Can you follow my steps? then you can get the whole flow then you can apply it to your API.

Comment: My problem is, I cant change the response body also the request is a post request .. Is it not possible to do it in `post` and get the value from the `Input Body`?

Comment: Can you draw detail of your input body and output body with picture, I need to understand your situation and want to item.

Comment: I update my OP with an image of my request .

Comment: I updated my answer, can you review it and confirm it?