# Postman flows gathering data

Tags: json, postman, postman-flows

I have 2 requests which returns data that i want to export to the log.

The first request returns a "name" and "id" per application.
Per application a body.data element is returned.

The second request uses the id to get the information.
The data per application is returned by 1 or more instances of body.data

I simply want to print the information per application with addition of the application name (only returned in the first request).

The printing of the information works, but i cannot add the name of the first request.
Also the sequence of writing to the log is not sequential.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I confused the `to print the information per application with addition of the application name` and ` I cannot add the name of the first request`. can you draw a picture with a diagram with inputs and outputs items for first request and second request? This is my diagram example in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76770321/postman-body-get-the-last-3-characters-on-the-username/76772257?noredirect=1#comment135408871_76772257) at [first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6hAv.png).